# Azure Data Flow or Data factory v2 how to Merge two tables like we use to use Merger in SSIS

Tags: azure-data-factory

What I am trying to achieve is to merge two tables sources and destination using merge in Azure data Flow or Data Factory, so it Deletes or Update or Insert data in respect to the Sources.

Preferring using Data flow

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join transformation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join

It even compares this transformation to the merge in SSIS.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a lot easier to convert objects to dataframes and work with those.  Something like this, perhaps.

```
result = DataFrame.join([other DataFrame], how='inner', on=None)
```